# Should I ignore the actions RIGHTFIRE and LEFTFIRE in the SpaceInvaders environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, gym, action-spaces

I'm trying to replicate the DeepMind DQN paper. I'm using OpenAI's Gym. I'm trying to get a decent score with Space Invaders (using `SpaceInvaders-v4` environment). I checked the actions available with `env.unwrapped.get_action_meanings()`, and I get this:

```
['NOOP', 'FIRE', 'RIGHT', 'LEFT', 'RIGHTFIRE', 'LEFTFIRE']
```

Checking the number of actions with `env.action_space.n` gives me a number of 6 actions.

The `RIGHTFIRE` and `LEFTFIRE` actions, I suppose, aren't used, given that they *seem* to do the same as `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, am I right?

If so, restricting the action size to the 4 first actions would improve my learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we shouldn't eliminate those actions, because `RIGHTFIRE` and `LEFTFIRE` do `RIGHT` + `FIRE` and `LEFT` + `FIRE`, respectively. So they are different actions. I post this just to clarify in case someone faces the same doubt.